# SQL - Keep only columns that have some field that don't match

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm updating a table daily, but I only want to update the rows that had any value modified from the previous day.

For example, I have 2 tables (Today and Yesterday):

Today:

| ID | NAME | MONTH | COUNTRY | YEAR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Sta | April | Jamaica | 1992 |
| 2 | Danny | November | France | 1982 |
| 3 | Elle | June | Australia | 2020 |
| 4 | John | April | Uruguay | 1765 |
| 5 | Paul | May | Canada | 1990 |

Yesterday:

| ID | NAME | MONTH | COUNTRY | YEAR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Sta | April | Jamaica | 1992 |
| 2 | Danny | November | Spain | 1982 |
| 3 | Elle | July | Australia | 2022 |
| 5 | Paul | May | Canada | 1990 |

So I want to create a table that only has ID 2, 3 and 4 from Today, because 1 or more fields changed, or the row appears in table Today but it doesn't appear in table Yesterday:

| ID | NAME | MONTH | COUNTRY | YEAR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | Danny | November | France | 1982 |
| 3 | Elle | June | Australia | 2020 |
| 4 | John | April | Uruguay | 1765 |

I tried to use the MINUS function, but I'm using MS-Access and it doesn't work. There are +100 columns, so I can't do something like:
WHERE Today.ID = Yesterday.ID AND (Today.NAME <> Yesterday.NAME OR Today.COUNTRY <> Yesterday.COUNTRY OR Today.YEAR <> Yesterday.YEAR)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst this is a nightmare using SQL, using VBA and a few loops it becomes relatively easy. Something like seems to work:

```
Sub sCheckDifference()
    On Error GoTo E_Handle
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rsToday As DAO.Recordset
    Dim rsYesterday As DAO.Recordset
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim strNoMatch As String
    Dim lngCount As Long
    Dim lngLoop1 As Long
    Set db = DBEngine(0)(0)
    db.Execute "DELETE * FROM tblNoMatch;"
    Set rsToday = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM tblToday;")
    If Not (rsToday.BOF And rsToday.EOF) Then
        lngCount = rsToday.Fields.Count - 1
        Do
            strSQL = "SELECT * FROM tblYesterday WHERE ID=" & rsToday!id
            Set rsYesterday = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
            If Not (rsYesterday.BOF And rsYesterday.EOF) Then
                For lngLoop1 = 1 To lngCount
                    If rsToday(lngLoop1) <> rsYesterday(lngLoop1) Then
                        strNoMatch = strNoMatch & rsToday!id & ","
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next lngLoop1
            Else    ' value doesn't exist in previous table
                strNoMatch = strNoMatch & rsToday!id & ","
            End If
            rsToday.MoveNext
        Loop Until rsToday.EOF
        If Len(strNoMatch) > 0 Then '   have found some differences
            If Right(strNoMatch, 1) = "," Then strNoMatch = Left(strNoMatch, Len(strNoMatch) - 1)
            strSQL = "INSERT INTO tblNoMatch SELECT * FROM tblToday WHERE ID IN(" & strNoMatch & ");"
            db.Execute strSQL
        End If
    End If
sExit:
    rsToday.Close
    rsYesterday.Close
    Set rsToday = Nothing
    Set rsYesterday = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
    Exit Sub
E_Handle:
    MsgBox Err.Description & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "sCheckDifference", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Error: " & Err.Number
    Resume sExit
End Sub
```

Note that `Name`, `Month` and `Year` are all reserved words in Access, so if these are the real field names they should be changed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from today as t
where not exists (select 1
                  from yesterday as y
                  where y.id = t.id and y.name = t.name and
                        y.month = t.month and y.country = t.country and
                        y.year = t.year
                 );
```

Comment: Yes, but I can't do that because I have +100 columns, so I can't write 100 AND. Is that the only solution?

Comment: @Dylan . . . In MS Access, you will need to list all the columns.